# How can I set two shapes to the same color in GIMP?

Tags: color, gimp

I have two shapes. The color of the first shape is `#C6C6C6` and the color of the second shape is `#3F3F3F`. I want to set same color for these shapes. I tried all options in the `Colors` menu, but every time, the colors are different. How can I set them to the same color?

I am using GIMP 2.8.20.

Comment: Your two colors are greys... Brightness doesn't work? If the shapes are actually one single uniform color on a transparent background, you can set the alpha-lock on one and paint it with the color of the other.

Comment: @xenoid I tried brightness but it did not work. can you give me more details. also same problem is available for different shades of red. if I have two shape with different shade of red. I want to paint them in blue. but shades are always different.

Comment: Try [rotate colors](https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-rotate-colormap.html)

Comment: Is the image in RGB mode?  Sounds like you're in Indexed mode.

Answer (score 1):

You have "shapes". I assume your image has separate parts that can easily be selected, NOT a complex photo from where no single item is easy to select for individual processing.

**Step 1:** So, select your shapes which you want to get the same color and move them to same layer, if they are in separate layers. Keep those shapes selected and be sure that nothing else is selected.

**Step 2:** Open Colours > Curves. Adjust the curve ends so that you have a straight absolutely horizontal line at y=128. That turns all selected to middle grey.

**Step 3:** Open Colours > Colourise an adjust the wanted color

This can be done separately for all shapes. => more repeating adjustments, but no need to move stuff between layers.

You can cut a shape from a layer and paste it accurately into the same place on another layer, if you do not lose the selection between cut and paste. If possible, select a little larger ara than the absolute minimum => no errors due the antialiasing.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the color picker tool, click on one of the shapes - that will select that color as foreground.

Then pick the "magic wand" tool, and click on the second shape - that will create a selection mask restricted to the area of that shape (selection masks can be more complicated to create for photographic images, or otherwise complex shapes, but you are mentioning plain monochrome shapes).

Finally, just drag the previously selected color, now displayed as "foreground color" on the toolbox to the image area: it should fill the selection making the second shape identical in color with other.

Remove the selection mask by selecting  `Select->None` and export your image.

Comment: This worked for me once, Gimp is different from ps in many good aspects.  What also worked on two separate layers was combining them and locking alpha then just filling the layer with ctrl+,

Answer (score 0):

If the two shapes are in different images, make sure that the target image is in RGB mode, and not in "indexed" mode (`Image>Mode>RGB`). In indexed-color mode the colors are restricted to those in the existing color map of the image.